# HTML5 SVG and mouse events

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I made a few hexagons with Inkscape and placed them in some HTML5. I got the onmouseover event to work but the onmouseout event does not work. I'm running this on Google Chrome 11.0.696.57 beta. Does anyone know what the problem is?

Here is link to HTML
https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B7ZCkMUvddWIOTAxNmJlYjctODNlOS00MzFlLTgwY2EtOTY1NzZkZGQ2Yjgx&sort=name&layout=list&num=50

Comment: Please put your relevant code in your post.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed a few thing in the example to fix it in chrome (the example dosen't work in safari, opera or IE9).

Firstly you had some semi colons after the onmouseover and onmouseout statements.

```
onmouseover = "Hilight(evt)"
onmouseout = "Darken(evt)"
```

Secondly the event was firing but the alpha was 0.06  I changed it to 0.6 and now it is much more obvious that it is firing:

```
function Darken(evt) {
     var GameSpace = evt.target;
     GameSpace.setAttribute("style", "fill-opacity: 0.6"); 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ERyS4/7/

Comment: I had the event firing because I can watch it with Chrome Dev tools but the change is not taking place. The opacity is staying the same. But It will change if I hit right mouse, Inspect Element and close that out. This change is shown instantly in Firefox.

Comment: I think I've discovered the problem. It seems Chrome has an issue with "fill-opacity". If I change the attribute to just "opacity" it works. Thanks for your help though. I wonder if there is a fix for this or do I just deal with it?

Comment: You should also remove <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?> for inline SVG. And by using "opacity" instead of "fill-opacity", you also affect the strokes. You can achieve the effect you want without JavaScript, with just CSS too (the ":focus" selector).